# jQuery Tag-It Customization

Tags: jquery, tag-it

I'm trying to customize the jQuery Tag-It widget (http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) for the following two behaviours:

1) Allow commas in tags (I can allow it by customizing triggerKeys() but the widget still doesn't allow commas in tags e.g. when i add a tag like "test," it will simply add it in as "test" and not show the comma). It does, however, remove "commas" as a tag trigger.

2) Allow duplicates (the widget currently doesn't allow me to add duplicate tags and there doesn't seem to be a method to allow this)

The other thing I wanted to ask related to this: are there any standards related to including jQuery widgets specifically with respect to including the multiple css and js files since multiple widgets utilize multiple files and there seems to be clashes between widgets I include on the site.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'll be much help to me. Otherwise, a widget with similar functionality (allowing duplicates, commas, dragging, closing).

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your comma separator can be found in the docs: [Tag-it docs][1]

Use singleFieldDelimiter to change the delimiter.

As for duplicates, why would you want to have duplicates if they are tags?


  [1]: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown

Comment: Thanks. I'll test with "singleFieldDelimiter". I'm actually allowing the user to enter any word (even duplicates) in input. You're right, technically this will not serve for tags - rather words in general.

Comment: I tried it with the singleField and singleFieldDelimiter options. The results the same. e.g. if I enter ",test" it shows up correct but if I enter "test," only "test" shows up.

Comment: What were you using as your delimiter and did you have ignore spaces on?

Answer (score 5):

I see that after few years it's still unanswered. I needed same from that plugin for hebrew language that have char character on comma key.
All you need is to comment this code inside the plugin:

```
c.which === b.ui.keyCode.COMMA
```

Comment: Or in version 2.0: event.which === $.ui.keyCode.COMMA  :)

Comment: @lazarus, your comment saved me a lot of time. Thank you. Why don't you edit the above answer to address your comment?

Answer (score 1):

I added an allowDuplicates option. I still haven't added a way to customize the trigger keys, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for adding support to Hebrew (and I believe other non-english languages like Arabic).
I'm using jQuery UI Tag-it!version v2.0 (06/2011).
The problem was that when typing the key ת in Hebrew a new tag was created becase the key ת is the same as the comma in English.
The code below verify that the typed **character value** is "," (comma) and not the **comma key-code**

```
 //  (event.which === $.ui.keyCode.COMMA && event.shiftKey === false) ||
      event.key === "," ||
```

[checking comma character and not comma key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efAxn.png)

Best regards,
Ariel